# Loading images from another LUA file - corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What I'm stuck trying to do is call certain image(s) from another lua file and load it in the game to save having to create them individually in each lua file that requires the images.

I have this character which I want to load in the menu.lua file and allow it to stay on screen when the game moves over to game.lua. So rather than having to create the character again in each file, i would like to make a simple call and allow it to stay until its been removed.

Thanks.

```
local jumpForce = 350
```

** Random player graphic **

```
Anims = {
 "images/birdAnim.png",
 "images/birdAnim2.png",
}
```

** Player animations **

```
local sheetData = {width=45, height=35, numFrames=2, sheetContentWidth=90,     sheetContentHeight=35}
local imagesheet = graphics.newImageSheet(Anims[math.random(1,2)], sheetData)
local sequenceData = {
  {name="hop", start=1, count=1, time=300},
  {name="drop", start=2, count=1, time=300}
}
```

** Create the player **

```
bird = display.newSprite(playerGroup, imagesheet, sequenceData)
bird.x = display.contentCenterX - 150
bird.y = 140       
bird.name = "bird"
physics.addBody( bird, "static", physicsData:get("player3") )
bird.isSensor = true 
bird:setSequence("drop")
bird:play()
group:insert(bird)
```

UPDATED!!

** Player handler **

```
local function movePlayer(event)
 if event.phase == "began" then
   bird:setLinearVelocity(0, -jumpForce)
   playSFX(sndJump)
   bird:setSequence("hop")
   bird:play()
 elseif event.phase == "ended" then
   bird:setSequence("drop")
   bird:play()
 end

 return true
end
```

** Player Listener **

```
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", movePlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us complete code?

the problem probably is that playerGroup is getting destroyed when you are switching from main to game.lua

You can create it without any parent and it will remain until you manually remove it

Comment: Will the animations sheets and data need to be declared twice? One for menu and one for game? Or will it be fine being in menu.lua only? I haven't yet set it up, right now it's just a standalone block of code that's only in the game.lua file. I would like to add it so that it is in menu file and crosses over to game, I just wasn't sure on how it can be done.

Comment: you should do it once and not put it into the group of scene (self.view)... just create group without parent and put everything inside it... assign to global variable and you can access it enverywhere

Comment: Hi iBad, Im struggling to understand how it should be put together and how its called in the menu.lua file. I removed the parent group and the image remained on the different screens however i get an error with the movePlayer function when trying to control the player in the next scene. I have provided all the code that relates to the player bird in my OP.

Comment: what does your error say? what is "group" and "playerGroup"?

Comment: The error says " attempt index global 'event' (a nil value) this is in a seperate file and is regarding the player handlers 1st event.phase line of code. I removed player group as it was just used to hold the player images

Comment: Probably you forgot to add param event to callback function.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch scenes, the imagesheet and sequencedata is removed. I suggest that you put them all in a separate LUA file so that corona can reference to it during scene changing. And make a global group that handles the object. Don't insert it to any groups in a scene.